# How to manage subview hierarchy in UIViewControler?

Tags: iphone, swift, view, hierarchy

If i have code like:

```
self.view.addSubview(SomeImage1)
self.view.addSubview(SomeImage2)
self.view.addSubview(SomeImage3)
```

How do I switch places of view, i understand that the first one would be at index 0 and second at index 1, so is there a way to manually set view index, i am new at managing view and havent found any tutorial good enough to solve my problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a full set of UIView methods that copes with that:

```
func bringSubviewToFront(_ view: UIView)
func sendSubviewToBack(_ view: UIView)
func removeFromSuperview()
func insertSubview(_ view: UIView, atIndex index: Int)
func insertSubview(_ view: UIView, aboveSubview siblingSubview: UIView)
func insertSubview(_ view: UIView, belowSubview siblingSubview: UIView)
func exchangeSubviewAtIndex(_ index1: Int, withSubviewAtIndex index2: Int)
```

...and so on.

You shouldn't be using array indexes to move views.